# How to readfile() in PHP while file being created (mp3)

Tags: php, mp3, readfile

I would like to set up a script that reads an mp3 file using the readfile function in PHP. Only problem is I do not want to wait for the mp3 file to be finished encoding before I start reading for the end user.

Comment: I think, you should use another function [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php)

Comment: You could check the tmp dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are spawning the encoder as a separate process from PHP, you should use [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to do so and instruct it to spew the encode at `stdout`. You can then easily use `fread` on the pipe that represents the encoder's standard output and forward whatever you read to the browser.

Something like this:

```
// Assuming that you have already sent the proper 
// HTTP headers to serve a download earlier

$handle = popen('encoder --param --output-to-stdout', 'r');
while (!$feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 2048); // or some other size, doesn't really matter
}
pclose($handle);
```

Comment: The encoding is being performed by python, and it only returns the name of the file and path before it starts encoding. Is there a way to  do this without getting involved with with any output streams?

Comment: @AdamCarpentieri: I cannot answer with 100% confidence, but I believe not. It would depend on lots of factors, most of which are not under your control. Try to `fopen` and `fread`, if it works: great, if not: you are out of luck.